# Oauth minitest error, callback link giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, minitest

I am trying to write tests for OmniAuth users and after setting up my test_helper, I am running into and a bad URI error.Sharing the details below:

> test_helper.rb

```
# OmniAuth auth mock for testing
  def setup_omniauth_mock (user)
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth::AuthHash.new ({
    'provider'            => 'google',
    'uid'                 => '123545',
    'user_id'             => '2',
    'first_name'          => 'X',
    'last_name'           => 'XYZ',
    'email'               => 'xxyz@example.com',
    'image'               => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com//photo.jpg',
    'oauth_token'         => 'abcdef12345',
    'oauth_expires_at'    => DateTime.now,
    })
    OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:google, OmniAuth::AuthHash.new)
    get '/auth/":google"/callback'
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]
    get '/auth/:google/callback'
  end
```

The error I am getting:

```
    test_validating_a_Google_OAuth_user#SessionsControllerTest (0.49s)
URI::InvalidURIError:         URI::InvalidURIError: bad
URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80/auth/":google"/callback
test/test_helper.rb:42:in `setup_omniauth_mock'
```

Now I followed the documentation here [Oauth Integration Testing][1]

[1]: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing but I think there is something I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help me guide through this.

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved it by cleaning things a bit.

My test_helper.rb now:

```
 # OmniAuth auth mock setup for testing
  setup do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] =
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]

  end

  #teardown OmniAuth mock setup
  teardown do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = false
  end

  #Google OAuth mock
  def google_oauth2_mock (user)
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google]
    OmniAuth::AuthHash.new ({
    'provider'            => 'google_oauth2',
    'uid'                 => '123545',
    'user_id'             => '2',
    'first_name'          => 'X',
    'last_name'           => 'XXYZ',
    'email'               => 'xxyzjam@example.com',
    'image'               => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/photo.jpg',
    'oauth_token'         => 'abcdef12345',
    'refresh_token'       => '12345abcdef',
    'oauth_expires_at'    => DateTime.now,
    })
  end
```

I put the routes in the individual tests, and that allowed me to run the tests suite smoothly.

Hope I am able to save you some time and frustrations.